# Multiple update queries in a single sql script file in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-scripts

I am in a situation where I need to update an oracle database table that contains different partitions.
I need to update the table partition wise and I need to update all the partitions in a `sql` script file. Below is an example of what I am trying to do :

```
update reporter_status partition(OCT17_4) set servername = 'AGG_P_31' where servername = 'AGG_P_3' ;

commit;

update reporter_status partition(NOV17_1) set servername = 'AGG_P_31' where servername = 'AGG_P_3' ;

commit;

update reporter_status partition(NOV17_2) set servername = 'AGG_P_31' where servername = 'AGG_P_3' ;

commit;

update reporter_status partition(NOV17_3) set servername = 'AGG_P_31' where servername = 'AGG_P_3' ;

commit;
```

I am thinking of writing above queries in a sql file and run it on the oracle database

Will this work, or are there any better options for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: This seems like a one-off exercise, so just run the script.

Comment: @Sarshad are you sure you can't simply use an IN-condition and partition pruning to get the relevant partitions?  There are only a few weird cases where it's important to hard-code the partition name.